# String out of bound error with even numbered length strings

Tags: java, string, recursion, indexoutofboundsexception, palindrome

I have written my version of method that tests whether a word is a palindrome or not. It seems to work well with odd numbered length strings but String Out of Bound Exception error occurs when tested with even numbered length.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
public static boolean palindrome(String s, int start, int end) {

int length = s.length();


        if (length%2 != 0 && start != end) {
            if (s.charAt(start) == s.charAt(end)) {
                return palindrome(s,start+1,end-1);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(length%2 == 0 && (start+1) != (end-1)) {
            if (s.charAt(start) == s.charAt(end)) {
                return palindrome(s,start+1,end-1);
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if(length%2 != 0 && start == end) {
            return true;
        }
        else if(length%2 == 0 && start+1 == end-1) {
            if (s.charAt(start+1) == s.charAt(end-1)) {
                return true;
            }
            else {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

Comment: I might be blind, but where do you check if `s` is not empty, `start` not negative and `end` not larger than `s.length()`?

Comment: You have a problem with the following if cases: ```else if(length%2 == 0 && (start+1) != (end-1))``` and ```else if(length%2 == 0 && start+1 == end-1)```. Take as input the string aa, which is a palindrome. start is zero and end is 1. When we get to one of these cases start+1 = 1 and end-1 = 0 and you call the method again and will get an index out of bounds exception. You can't increase/decrease both indices. Try only increasing/decreasing one.

Comment: Thanks for all the suggestions - I will try them now!

Comment: Do you really need to implement the palindrome function this way? If you can, why not just use the check `s.equals(new StringBuilder(s).reverse().toString())`

Comment: I need to incorporate recursion into my method! I know it's inefficient but I thought I'll worry about that after I have a working code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is a bit unnecessary complicated, you are using indexes to do what you can do with substring in java. Also, you have many cases for even or odd numbers that you could avoid, by just considering them in your base case. I tried to keep your approach and reduced the code as much as possible. I think is much cleaner. In the base case if the number is odd it will end up at the 1 and if it is even it will end up at 2.

```
public boolean isPalindrome(String string)
{
    if (string.length() > 2) {
        if (string.charAt(0) == string.charAt(string.length() - 1)) {
            return this.isPalindrome(string.substring(1, string.length() - 1));
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (string.length() == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (string.charAt(0) == string.charAt(1)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```